# variable containing a string fails == test with 'the same' string. Why?

Tags: java

I'm an idiot:

My code is the code below. I ran the code, and input 4 as my answer. However, the program still tells me the answer is incorrect. What did I do wrong? Thank you so much for the help.

```
import java.io.*;

class class1 {

  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException { 
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("What is the answer to 2 + 2");
    String answer;

    answer = input.readLine();

    if ( answer == "4"){
      System.out.println("Correct");
    } else System.out.println("Incorrect");

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't compare strings using `==`. You need to do it like this:

```
answer.equals("4");
```

The reason is because `==` only works if both sides are the exact same object (the same instance). What you really need is to check if both strings have identical content.

More specifically, `==` in your example compares to see if `answer` points to the same object as `"4"`, which it doesn't.

More technical detail: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to do numerical comparisons

```
if(Integer.valueOf(answer) == 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
if ( answer == "4")
```

with:

```
if (answer.equals("4"))
```